# Is there a way to use pure RESTful API to access DropBox rather than using its SDK?

Tags: rest, dropbox

I see there are numerous examples to access the Dropbox service by its SDK. I need use RESTful API to access both Dropbox and another service provider which is similar as Dropbox but doesn't provide an SDK. So I plan to encapsulate a unified interface.

But Dropbox's website https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs has no clear flow to describe how to use a pure RESTful API to do what SDK does. I'm curious if some sample code did that?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the official documentation:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs

Note that the above link is to the old and deprecated v1 API.

Here's the HTTP API docs for the current v2 API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation

Comment: A link is not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/385431/Android-RESTful-OAuth-upload-file-to-Dropbox#_rating

Its all there

Comment: A link is not an answer.